# How to change the date format using php

Tags: php, regex

i have a date format like this **Tue, 23 Dec 2014 02:24:00 +0000** ..

i would like to convert that using php to something like this   **August 16, 1998, 03:00:00**

any idea on how to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Split your dates in array and pass array elements in date() function with mktime() parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use `date` and `strtotime` built-in function :

```
$date=date("F j, Y, H:i:s", strtotime("Tue, 23 Dec 2014 02:24:00 +0000 ") );
var_dump($date);
```

*Note: Always read the documentation*